# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() CacheController.php on line 82

Tags: cache, magento1.9.3

I am not able to enable cache from admin panel and `system.log` file generate below error :

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CacheController.php on line 82

can any one help me please?

Comment: Could you post the full code in cachecontroller.php ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are referring

```
public function massEnableAction()
{
    $types = $this->getRequest()->getParam('types');
    $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();

    $updatedTypes = 0;
    foreach ($types as $code) {
        if (empty($allTypes[$code])) {
            $allTypes[$code] = 1;
            $updatedTypes++;
        }
    }
    if ($updatedTypes > 0) {
        Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__("%s cache type(s) enabled.", $updatedTypes));
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*');
}
```

Have you customized admin? It seems your request is missing `types` parameter, which indicates the cache types to enable